# if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable in $[0,1] \Rightarrow f$ is bounded in $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I know this is almost trivial or evident, but I wanted to be sure if any Lebesgue integrable function on a compact set is bounded or not. I hope it is true because I'm using that fact for solving some of my problems. If it is not true, please provide a counterexample. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not true: let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $0<x\leq 1$, with $f(0)$ defined however you want. Then $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ but not bounded.

Comment: An even more pathological example might be $f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \chi_{\{1/n\}}$, which is unbounded, integrable, and indeed $\int f = 0$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm not sure what you are thinking.

Comment: @zhw If $x = 1/n$, then $f(x) = n$.  Otherwise, it is zero.  $f$ is nonzero on a null set, thus it integrates to zero.  Therefore unbounded and integrable, which provides another counterexample for Richard Clare.

Comment: OK, I read it as $\chi_{[0,1/n]},$ my mistake.

Comment: @zhw Yeah, the tiny comment font makes it hard to read, but it didn't seem interesting enough to give as another answer.